# OpenCV stereo images c++

Tags: opencv

```
VideoCapture capleft(0);     
VideoCapture capright(1);
//int width=640, height = 480;
Mat frameLeft,frameRight,both;
both= Mat(1080,1920,CV_MAKETYPE(8,3),CV_RGB(255,255,255));


if(!capleft.isOpened() || !capright.isOpened())
{
    cout<<"Please check your connection!"<<endl;
    system ("pause");
    return -1;
}

while(true)
{                  
    capleft>>frameLeft; 
    capright>>frameRight;

    if(frameLeft.data==NULL|| frameRight.data==NULL)
        break;

    frameLeft.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(50,50,960,1080)));  
    frameRight.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(693,50,960,1080)));
    imshow("images", both);
    waitKey(30);

    switch(waitKey(30))
    {
        case 27:
        return 0;
    }           
} 
return 0;
```

}

I'm trying to adjust the resolution to 1080,960 left and 1080,960 right. This code works if I change

```
frameLeft.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(50,50,960,1080))); // 960->640 and 1080->480 
frameRight.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(693,50,960,1080)));
```

Otherwise, I get the error:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x7781D8A8 in Playing_images2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017F628.

I will really appreciate if some one can guide me.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Please edit your code correctly, and add errors

Comment: And where do you change the values to change the resolution?

Comment: Unhandled exception at at 0x7781D8A8 in Playing_images2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017F628.

Comment: frameLeft.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(50,50,640,480)));  // 640 to 960, 480 to 1080
frameRight.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(693,50,640,480)));

Comment: I've edited the question to include the error. In the future, @skyrocket, please *edit* your question to include these sorts of details when others ask for them in comments. You can reply to the comment saying that you've edited if you want. It would be even better if they were included in the first place, though...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accessing memory outside of the image. Try using [hconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) for a safer way of concatenating images.

Remove the line

```
both= Mat(1080,1920,CV_MAKETYPE(8,3),CV_RGB(255,255,255));
```

and replace

```
frameLeft.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(50,50,960,1080)));  
frameRight.copyTo(Mat(both,Rect(693,50,960,1080)));
```

with

```
hconcat(std::vector<Mat>{frameLeft, frameRight}, both);
```

Comment: Thanks @morotspaj for reply. Apparently, I'm very new to openCV and programming. I would really appreciate if you can tell me how can I implement this to my full code.

Comment: thanks. I get the following errors: IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "hconcat" matches the argument list argument types are: (<error-type>) 
IntelliSense: type name is not allowed 
IntelliSense: expected a ')'